# HTML textarea does not work after manual deleting of input

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, default

I have a html site with an input and output textarea. By pressing a button it changes the value of the input textarea into the output textarea by a JavaScript function.

This works fine, but if i delete afterwards the value in the output textarea the procedure does not work anymore. Anyone have a clue why not?

I already tried to set the output textarea value on "default" by clicking the button before starting a new procedure.

Minimal code:

```
<textarea placeholder="Input" id="input"></textarea>
<button type="submit" onclick="toHTML(jQuery('#output'),Cipher.encrypt(jQuery('#input').val(),'X'));output.select();output.focus()">Encrypt</button>            
<textarea placeholder="Output" id="output"></textarea>
```

With `Cipher.encrypt` being the function used by pressing the button.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. We can't help you fix broken code, if we can't see the code.

Comment: Edited, but it is really straight forward.

Comment: What is that `toHTML` function?

Comment: `function toHTML(holder, result)
{
 holder.empty();
 holder.append(result);
}`
This is the function in the JavaScript file.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to delete textarea contents with Javascript this way:

```
$("#input").val('');
```

And than it will work